# Issue with selectively deleting jenkins data in tables in InfluxDB 1.8

Tags: database, jenkins, influxdb

I am using the jenkins influxdb plugin (v3.7) to log jenkins job results to an instance of InfluxDB (1.8).
I want to delete the rows of jenkins data where the project_name (job) has been deleted from jenkins itself.
Currently, the project_name is both a tag and a field. I can delete tags but not fields per the official documentation. When I run:
`DELETE FROM jenkins_data WHERE project_name = <deleted_job>` I receive this error:
`fields not supported in WHERE clause during deletion`
**How can I tell influx that I mean the tag and not the key when deleting?**

Note: I tried both show field keys and show tag keys and project_name was found in both results under the jenkins table

When I run:
`DELETE FROM jenkins_data WHERE project_name = <deleted_job>` I receive this error:
`fields not supported in WHERE clause during deletion`